# unique field in the model

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

i am looking for a solution to make one of the data field as unique field in the model in sencha, somehow i am not able to find documentation for it. Here is the code

```
Ext.define('handfree.model.CategoryM', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.identifier.Uuid'
    ],
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'name',     type: 'string' }
        ],
        idProperty: 'id',
        identifier : 'uuid'
    }
});
```

I need 'name' field to be unique. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are manually popping records into a store, you can put a listener on your store, and when a record is added, unset it.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-addrecords

Comment: that's good suggestion, in fact i was using looping method to filter out duplicate record in the "name" field of above case, They are same theory but yours much better. Is there any configuration in the model that allowing avoid duplicate record in certain field to achieve "unique"